# python for loop makes extra listing

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list,and if i find a word in text file matching the list ,then it has to print 'yes' else print 'no'.If I increase the list then it is producing a large list.

Coding:

```
keywords=['good','lorry','truck']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               a = 'yes'
            else:
                a = 'no'
            print a
```

I have a text file qwe.txt as:

```
i havea bike good
condition
yes
I have a car
Skoda Superb
yes good
```

its producing:

```
yes
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
yes
no
no
```

Instead of Desired:

```
yes
no
no
no
no
no
yes
```

Please ,help me in reducing the extra 'no'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
keywords=['good','lorry','truck']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               a = 'yes'
               break
            else:
                a = 'no'
        print a
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't print 'no' until you've made it all the way through the list of keywords:

```
keywords=['good','lorry','truck']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        a = 'no'  # Start by assuming it's not there
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               a = 'yes'
               break  # Now that we've found a match, we can stop looking
        print a
```

Also note you can simplify the code a bit with a generator expression and the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
keywords=['good','lorry','truck']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        a = 'yes' if any(key in line for key in keywords) else 'no'
        print a
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for membership in a group is what [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is good at:

```
keywords=set(['good','lorry','truck'])
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if keywords.intersection(line.split()):
            print 'yes'
        else:
            print 'no'
```

Comment: Yes, a set will improve performance quite a bit here; look ups will be O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: but it says attribute error :list has no attribute intersection!

Comment: @user3886307 - Do you see where I assign to the `keywords` variable? See how I created a `set` from the `list` that you had in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keywords=['good','lorry','truck']
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        found_match="no"
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
                found_match="yes"
        print found_match
```

Gotta be careful with your indentation. You had one print statement for every "key", for every "line". With 3 keys and 6 (maybe seven if you have a blank line at the bottom) lines, you get 3*6=18 responses.